# dynamic casting

Tags: c#, casting

How do I cast a parameter passed into a function at runtime?

```
private object PopulateObject(object dataObj, System.Data.DataRow dataRow, string query)
{


    object = DataAccess.Retriever.RetrieveArray<dataObj.GetType()>(query);
```

i'd like to know how to get dataObj.GetType()  inside the type declaration at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private T PopulateObject<T>(T dataObj, System.Data.DataRow dataRow, string query)
{
    dataObj = DataAccess.Retriever.RetrieveArray<T>(query);
}
```

This will allow you to avoid any reflection in this method as the type argument supplied to `PopulateObject` will also be the type argument for `RetrieveArray`.  By calling this method the compiler will be able to infer the type of `T`, allowing you to avoid writing runtime type checking.

Comment: Now just hope Retriever isn't a ContextBoundObject.

Comment: Since ContextBoundObjects cannot have generic methods I think we are OK to assume that the "Retriever" type does not inherit from "ContextBoundObject" since it is exposing a generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, because variable declaration happens at compile time, not runtime. You should create a generic method.

```
private T PopulateObject<T>(T dataObj, DataRow dataRow, String query)
{
    return DataAccess.Retriever.RetrieveArray<T>(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to set a generic type parameter at runtime?

You'll need Reflection here - [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)

Note: When the Type can be determined at compile-time, rewrite this using a type parameter.

```
private T PopulateObject<T>(T dataObj, System.Data.DataRow dataRow, string query)
{
    dataObj = DataAccess.Retriever.RetrieveArray<T>(query);
}
```